# How do I do max pooling on sift features

Tags: opencv, max, sift, pooling

I want to use sparse local descriptors for image classification. the one step in sparse representation is max pooling. local descriptors like sift has 64 dimensions. I by densefeaturedetector function in opencv extract 1225 vectors from an image. I don't know , How do I do max pooling on this sift features.